# no output in being received when starting a process through System.Diagnostics.Process - c#

Tags: c#-4.0, process, system.diagnostics

i am creating a process using System.DIagnostics.Process in c#
i have created a class `CCProcess` inherited from the `Process` class
the problem is that ErrorDataRecieved OR OutputDataReceived are not being fired..
herez my code

```
public CCProcess(string executablePath, string[] parameters, CCProcessInfo processInfo)
        {
            this.ProcessInfo = processInfo;
            this.OutputMessages = new List<ProcessOutputMessage>();
            this.ProcessId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            base.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            this.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executablePath)
            {
                Arguments = string.Join(" ", parameters.Select(s => string.Format("\"{0}\"", s))),
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                ErrorDialog = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            this.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                this.OutputMessages.Add(new ProcessOutputMessage() { Message = e.Data, Type = OutputType.Error });
                if (this.ErrorData_Recieved != null&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    this.ProcessInfo.LastResponseFromProcess = DateTime.Now;
                    this.ErrorData_Recieved(e.Data);
                }
            };

            this.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                this.OutputMessages.Add(new ProcessOutputMessage() { Message = e.Data, Type = OutputType.Output });
                if (OutputData_Recieved != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    this.ProcessInfo.LastResponseFromProcess = DateTime.Now;
                    OutputData_Recieved(e.Data);
                }
            };
        }
```

what am i doing wrong?
the code provided is the constructor of the class `CCProcess`

Comment: Why a downvote? on a question that is complete and has been answered by myself 4 year ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oooh i hate this.. posting question here and then answering them.. anyways
i was missing a bery basic thing
`Process.BeginOutputReadLine()`
wasted 2 hours because of this 
more about this here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline